# how can I plot the following figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot

How can I plot following figure without the airplane? $l_1$ on the left and right are in the same line, so is $l_2$. Many thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: That's mostly just some straight lines, have you tried anything?

Comment: Questions that look like "Please do this
complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too 
localized" or "too broad". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a
[minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your effort in solving the problem:
you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Such a nice nickname choice for a do-it-for-me :) Any Tesla's around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you've tagged this `tikz-pgf`, but since there are [plenty of TikZ tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=tikz+tutorial), here is a commented version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) which is an alternative drawing tool that you might like to learn.

Compile this with `lualatex` (or work out how to adapt it for plain Metapost, or [GMP](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en)).

[image]

One generally useful thing shown here is how to do the equivalent of a TikZ `scope` shift in Metapost, by shifting the `currentpicture` variable half way through.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    % first make useful star shaped path
    path pentagram; pentagram = for t=0 upto 4: up rotated 144 t -- endfor cycle; 

    % now make a drawing with the common parts
    picture base;
    base = image(
        % define the four lines...
        path a, b, c, d;  
        a = (left -- right) scaled 80;                
        b = a shifted 48 up;
        c = (down -- 3 up) scaled 16 shifted 60 left;
        d = (down -- 3 up) scaled 16 shifted 60 right;

        % draw the lines...
        draw a withcolor 1/2 white; 
        draw b withcolor 1/2 white;

        drawoptions(withcolor 1/2 [blue, white]);
        draw c dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
        draw d dashed evenly scaled 1/2;

        % add some decorations
        drawoptions(withcolor 1/4 [blue, white]);
        drawarrow point 0 of c -- point 0 of d;
        fill pentagram scaled 4 shifted (a intersectionpoint c);
        fill pentagram scaled 4 shifted point 1 of d;
        drawoptions();

        % add some labels to the lines
        label.rt("$l_1$", point 1 of a);
        label.rt("$l_2$", point 1 of b);
        label.bot("$u$",  point 0 of c);
        label.bot("$v$",  point 0 of d);
    );

    % now draw the base image, and add the track
    % slightly shortened so it looks better with the markers
    draw base;
    drawarrow ((-60,0) -- (-30, 48) -- (60, 48)) 
        cutbefore fullcircle scaled 10 shifted (-60,0)
        cutafter  fullcircle scaled 10 shifted (60,48)
        dashed evenly 
        withpen pencircle scaled 1 
        withcolor red;

    % shift the whole picture 200 to the left
    currentpicture := currentpicture shifted 200 left;

    % and draw the base again, but with a different track and a label
    draw base;
    drawarrow ((-60,0) -- (-30, 0) -- (0, 48) -- (60, 48)) 
        cutbefore fullcircle scaled 10 shifted (-60,0)
        cutafter  fullcircle scaled 10 shifted (60,48)
        dashed evenly 
        withpen pencircle scaled 1 
        withcolor red;
    dotlabel.bot("$A$", (-30,0));

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```